# Hide/Show between Distance in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

there are 4 objects A B C D
(A=cube1, B=Player, C=cover, D=cap1)
D is C's child

If the distance(between A,B) is getting closer, then hidden object C is changing to SetActive(true)
so I'd like to show object C but it doesn't work.

what sould i have to change?

```
    public class distance : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cube1;
    public GameObject Player;
    public GameObject cover;
    public GameObject cap1;
    float cubeDistance;

    void Start()
    {
        cubeDistance = Vector3.Distance(cube1.transform.position, Player.transform.position);
        Debug.Log(cubeDistance);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
            if (cubeDistance < 30)
            { GameObject.Find("cover").transform.Find("cap1").gameObject.SetActive(true); }
            else { GameObject.Find("cover").transform.Find("cap1").gameObject.SetActive(false); }           
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What is not happening and what is happening now? Please explain a bit

Comment: You already have references of gameobject 'cap1'. So do the following : if (cubeDistance < 30) { cap1.SetActive(true);} else { cap1.SetActive(false);}

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (cubeDistance < 30){ 
     cap1.SetActive(true);
 }
 else { 
     cap1.SetActive(false); 
 }
```

Use the gameobject references to make the object active/inactive in the game.

**Note**: GameObject.Find is a heavy operation and should not be called in Update as it will effect the performance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you are checking the distance one time only, in the `Start` function. To check the distance between A and B, you need to calculate the distance every frame in `Update` first. So you should put the distance code you are using into `Update`, before you check if the distance is less than 30.

Comment: Thanks i didn't think in that way 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: No problem :) Could you also select my answer as the correct one? Thanks